# Remove spaces and accents from a value field to put it in a From Email Adress field - dynamic sender profile

Tags: marketing-cloud, dynamic, custom-profile, replace, remove

I need to remove spaces and accents (special characters) and capital letters from the 'From Email Address' field in the sender profile. Indeed, I would like to compose a dynamic From Email Address in the sender profile based on the Salesforce CRM account name (which would be a variable) and a static domain name which is verified. The account name is retrieved from Salesforce as the journey data entry is Salesforce data entry.

1. I would like to concat the account name and the static domain name
2. I would like to know how to remove the capital letters, the accents (eg :'à', 'â', 'é', 'ê', 'è', 'ù') and the spaces that can be in the field account name.

--> Example of desired output :  If the field value on the account name is 'John Dôe' and the verified static domain name is '@digitalforu.com', the output should be 'johndoe@digitalforu.com'.

How can I proceed to do these actions ? I had put the following code in the 'From Email Address' field in sender profile but I do not know how to solve the issue of accents, spaces and capital letters that can appear in the account name.

```
%%[set @accountname = AttributeValue("Opportunity:Account:Name") if not empty (@accountname) then set @FromEmailAddress = CONCAT(@accountname, "@digitalforu.com") else set @FromEmailAddress ="@digitalforu.com" endif ]%% %%=v(@FromEmailAddress)=%%
```

Answer (score 1):

Honestly there is no simple solution here so it is gonna be a mess and far from efficient in AMPscript. Would be better to manipulate prior to send. Below is partial example on approach:

```ampscript
%%[
set @accountname = replacelist(replacelist(lowercase(AttributeValue("Opportunity:Account:Name")),"a","à","á","â","ã","ä","å","æ","ā","ă","ą"),"c","ç",ć","č")...etc per symbol letter
```

Breakout example to build from

```ampscript
/* Set attribute to var */
Set @accountname = AttributeValue("Opportunity:Account:Name")

/* push to lowercase */
Set @accountname = lowercase(@accountname)

/* replacelist for each version of 'a' with symbols */
Set @accountname = replacelist(@accountname,"a","à","á","â","ã","ä","å","æ","ā","ă","ą")

/* continue this for each letter that can have symbols */

/* remove spaces */
Set @accountname = replace(@accountname," ","")
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use a combination of AMP Script and SSJS to handle this. I would setup the workflow as follows:

**Step 1) Get the Value**

```
%%[
    SET @accountname = AttributeValue("Opportunity:Account:Name")
]%%

<script runat="server" language="javascript">
   set accountname = Variable.GetValue("@accountname");
</script>
```

**Step 2) Remove the Accents**

There are plenty of examples on how to do this via JS that I won't write a solution but I'll link out to a Stackoverflow article ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/990904/remove-accents-diacritics-in-a-string-in-javascript)). The accepted answer using maps would be supported in SSJS on SFMC.

**Step 3) Set the Value**

```
<script runat="server" language="javascript">
   set accountname = result; // result from stackoverflow
   Variable.SetValue("@accountname ", accountname);
</script>
```

At the end of Step 3; you have a non-accented `accountname` on which you can do any if, else checks that you like to derived your `FromAddress`.